# Entity Framework 6 - Referencing Table - How to write custom naviagtion-property-logic?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In a database, where we are not allowed to make huge changes, we have among other tables following tables (not relevant columns are hidden behind [some other columns...]):

**Master**

```
Id, [some other columns...]
```

**Table1**

```
Id, [some other columns...]
```

**Table2**

```
Id, [some other columns...]
```

**References**

```
Id, MasterId, TableName, ForeignId
```

We are using **EF6** (Code first, *data annotations preferred*) to access the database.

Now we like to be able to navige in our code e.g through "master.References.First().ReferenceRow" to the referenced tables. In this case "ReferenceRow" could be a navigation property, where we need to put some extra custom logic behind the "mapping", like "take a look at value TableName, if Table1 take the row from *Table1* where Id = ForeignId, else if *Table2*... " The column *TableName* would be something like discriminator column in TPH. I think that there is no out of the box solution for that scanario in EF, but is it possible to add this logic to a navigation property?

Of course we could create a abstract class "RefereceTable" and let all tables that could be referenced inherit it. But in this case TPH would create to much columns. TPC and TPT would not give us the performance that we want. This is the reason, why we cant't use theese inheritance type as-they-are to solve that problem. Also the only common column of that table would be the Id-column.

This is the reason we want to know: Is there a way to implement custom logic behind navigation properties that would solve our problem?

Comment: That sort of logic should not be in a navigation property. It belongs somewhere in the repository layer. So a function like GetReferencesByMasterId(int masterId) can have the code to look through different navigational properties..

Comment: @tranceporter Yeah, thats right and thats our actual situation, and it is ok for reading. But for inserting we have some problem: Lets say that we want to insert one row in Master, one row in Table1 and one row in References that links the other ones together. We don't know the Id of the Table1-Row before it was saved, so we have to call SaveChanges() again, to save the References-row. That will result to a second transaction. And facing that problem, caused me to thing about the above question.

Comment: Do entities have a row in each table?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you do not need to worry about the Id of the Table1-Row. EF will handle it for you. All you need to do is construct the hierarchy of entities and call SaveChanges once.

```
var master = _context.Master.Create();
master.property1 = "xyz";

var table1Row = _context.Table1.Create();
table1Row.property1 = "abc";

var referenceRow1 = _context.Reference.Create();
referenceRow1.MasterId = master.Id;
referenceRow.TableRow1Id = table1Row.Id;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Something along these lines should do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It seems that this is not working, because References.ForeignId is not declared as a foreignkey of some table. It has no reference because we could not know on witch table it will reference at design time. Setting the masterId is working fine, but ForeignId gets the value of 0. Any other ideas?

Comment: In that case rather than having a single ForeignId column I would have multiple columns like Table1Id, Table2Id, and get rid of the TableName column. This way you can create foreign keys and then put check constraints on Table1Id and Table2Id if required. (Like Table1Id is null && Table2Id is null is invalid, which can be trapped via check constraint). IMO that's a better database design and will ensure better data integrity.

Comment: Changing the database-design like this, would work fine for our application. But there are other applications using that database, so that is not possible without a lot of work on other applications. Sure it would work, but this is not want we want... sorry...